# JSMX ajax API not passing form variables to page with ie7

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a couple of pages working with Firefox but [JSMX](http://www.lalabird.com/) isn't passing the form variables through when using IE7.

Has anybody experienced this?

Answer (score 1):

1. I did a search, here at SO, for "JSMX".   This is the only question that was found.
2. The [JSMX website](http://www.lalabird.com/) lists the "Latest News" at Feb. 10th, 2008.
3. jQuery does everything JSMX does, and easier too.  jQuery also does much, much more.
4. jQuery has a huge install base, tons of support and even free script-hosting by Google, Microsoft, etc.

So, the answer is forget JSMX and use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).